# Annotate Matplotlib: does not show annotation on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

```
plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale[2:], label='# of Airline Passengers')
plt.plot(results_AR.fittedvalues[2:], color='red', label='ARIMA Fitted Values')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.annotate('rss is ', xy =(1950, 6.25))
plt.title('Fitted versus Original Values')
```

x value range from year 1950 - 1960
y value range from 0 to 6.5

The annotation doesn't show up on the graph.
I want the annotation somewhere on this graph.
[image: Graph]

Here is the data:

[image: Data]

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] (including some sample data).

Comment: Kraigolas, I just added the graph and the a pic of the data. The dates on the x axis ... y axis is the data points.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong coordinate for the annotation, as you are providing the integer number `1950` as the x-coordinate for a datetime axis.

You need to convert that number to a date. Replace this:

```py
plt.annotate('rss is ', xy =(1950, 6.25))
```

with this:

```py
import datetime as dt
plt.annotate('rss is ', xy =(dt.datetime.strptime("1950-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 6.25))
plt.ylim(0, 7)
```